# Finding Missing Quarters for last years in data

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe with Quarterly data in that. The data is in the following format

```
2022-03-01     abc
2022-06-01     xyz
2000-03-01     abcd
```

Starting from the very first date (somewhere around 1960's) I need to find if there are any quarters missing from the date. And for the current year, any quarters that have passed. For example for 2022 checking only first 3 quarters if the data exists for those.

the code i have written works fine for the previous years but takes a few lines to code for the whole scenario to cover.

I am looking for a one liner kind of code if possible.

i am looking for all quarters in all years except for 1965 as there is no full quarter data is available for that year (Just one year is an exception)

My code is something as under.

```
qtrs = df.groupBy(year("mydate").alias("q_count")).count().filter(col("count")!= 4).filter(~col("qtr_count").isin(1965)).collect()

If len[qtrs] !=0:
  return ("Error")
```

The above works for previous years but for the current year i have to write a separate logic. Is there a way I can incorporate the complete logic in the above one liner ? to check all the quarters.

Simply i want to make sure that no quarters are missing from the data starting from particular year Up until the last Quarter of the current year.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# I purposely commented out some part of 2022 so you can see the result

data = [
    ['2020-03-01', 'x']
,   ['2020-04-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-05-01', 'x']
,   ['2020-06-01', 'x']
,   ['2020-01-01', 'y']  
,   ['2020-01-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-07-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-08-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-09-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-10-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-11-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-12-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-03-01', 'x']
,   ['2021-04-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-05-01', 'x']
,   ['2021-06-01', 'x']
,   ['2021-01-01', 'y']  
,   ['2021-01-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-07-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-08-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-09-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-10-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-11-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-12-01', 'y']
,   ['2022-03-01', 'x']
,   ['2022-04-01', 'y']
,   ['2022-05-01', 'x']
,   ['2022-06-01', 'x']
,   ['2022-01-01', 'y']  
,   ['2022-01-01', 'y']
,   ['2022-07-01', 'y']
# ,   ['2022-08-01', 'y']
# ,   ['2022-09-01', 'y']
# ,   ['2022-10-01', 'y']
# ,   ['2022-11-01', 'y']
# ,   ['2022-12-01', 'y']    
    
]

cols = ['mydate', 'id']

# Creating Dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

# Group by year(mydate)
# Aggregate by year(mydate) and count distinct the quarter(mydate) where year(mydate) is not 1965
# Filter for years where the count(quarter(mydate)) != 4

res = df.groupBy(F.year('mydate').alias("q_count")).agg(F.countDistinct(F.quarter('mydate')).alias("qrt_count")). where(F.year('mydate') != 1965).filter(F.col('qrt_count') != 4)

res.display()
```

**Here is the output:**

[image]

Comment: This is what i have already done. the issue is to include the past quarters of the current year. So for 2022 it should not give this error. as there are only 3 quarters past in 2022.

Comment: Hey Mdahm,
if you see my initial comment in the code, I purposely commented out thee last dates in the dataset.

If uncomment them, the error will not show.

Comment: Hey Andrea, Thanks for your reply. Firt of all the data should be in the following order data = [
    ['2020-03-01', 'x']
,   ['2020-06-01', 'y']
,   ['2020-09-01', 'x']
,   ['2020-12-01', 'x']
,   ['2021-03-01', 'x']
,   ['2021-06-01', 'y']
,   ['2021-09-01', 'x']
#,   ['2021-12-01', 'x']
,   ['2022-03-01', 'x']
,   ['2022-06-01', 'y']
,   ['2022-09-01', 'x']
,   ['2022-12-01', 'x']
]
error should not appear on 2022 - 3 Quarters as these are the quarters passed in this year so far. so in this scenario there shouldn't be any errors. only error should pop if < 4 qtrs in yr < 2022

Comment: Hey Andrea, This is the scenario I want to handle that if the quarters are less than 4 in past years it should show year and quarters for that in dataframe, and if the quarters in data are less than actual quarters passed in current year, only then the error should pop.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the sample data that you have provided and created a dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [ ['2020-03-01', 'x'] , ['2020-06-01', 'y'] , ['2020-09-01', 'x'] , ['2020-12-01', 'x'] , ['2021-03-01', 'x'] , ['2021-06-01', 'y'] , ['2021-09-01', 'x'] , ['2021-12-01', 'x'] , ['2022-03-01', 'x'] , ['2022-06-01', 'y'] , ['2022-09-01', 'x'] , ['2022-12-01', 'x'] ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema=['date', 'id'])
display(df)
```

[image]

- Now, I have used the following code to get the desired output. Since you don't want to consider the current year and the year `1965`.

```
import datetime

df.filter((year('date') != datetime.datetime.today().year) | (month('date') != datetime.datetime.today().month)).groupBy(year('date').alias("quarter_year"))\
    .agg(countDistinct(quarter('date')).alias("past_quarter_count"))\
    .where((year('date') != 1965)).filter((col('past_quarter_count') < 4))\
    .filter((col('quarter_year') != datetime.datetime.today().year) | (col('past_quarter_count') < (datetime.datetime.today().month - 1)//3))\
    .show()
```

[image]

- Let's say I take out `2020-09-01` and test the code, then it would return the following result.

[image]

- If I take out both `2022-03-01` and `2020-09-01`, then the result would be as following:

[image]

Comment: Hi Saideep Thanks for that. It should also give error if i take out  Quarters 1,2,3 of the current year as these are the quarters passed in this year and data should exist for all past quarters of the years from 1966 to date. I was able to do what you have done with the exception of current year's quarters.

Comment: Check the updated the code in the solution.